# How to make an android app that cuts/slices images, saves each pieces and then reassembles each piece in one (original) image

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a total beginner at android development. I want to make an android app like this (in the android studio if possible): An app that allows us to slice photos and make pieces with random straight lines (in any angle, any number of lines that we want), then able to save those pieces as separate files and remember their id's, so when the next time we import those pieces in our app, it joins and makes whole one piece of the photo (original). is that possible? I don't know where to start. there are lots of photo editing app-making tutorials but I want this one.

For a simple explanation, I've also attached a photo.

[image: App Explanation diagram]

Comment: it is possible. https://gist.github.com/madan712/3672616 this might help

Comment: @JAMSHAID thank you for the suggestion, but It's not about making rectangular pieces. my requirement is to create pieces by making random lines.

Comment: Can you narrow down what exactly it is you are having difficulties with? Because writing a complete app is not a trivial task and requires lots of code. Is it perhaps what kind of data you need to store in order to be able to reconstruct the original image from its pieces?

Comment: @Jolly To be honest, I need a code/syntax for making pieces of photo, saving them and retrieve whole photo from pieces (as I am very beginner at coding). I am not saying I need a whole full written ready made source code but even some of starting ideas will be helpful. and for the matter of data storing, I mentioned as per my prediction (cause when application imports pieces, it may need some mapping data to join pieces together, like where the piece was placed etc...), if we achieve above task in any other way, there is no need to store data along with pieces.
Thank u v. much for responding

Comment: As for the image slices: I think most image data formats only allow rectangular images, but in order to save slices, you can simply add transparent pixels to make a full rectangular image for each slice. As for reconstruction data, I suggest you simply save the position of the top left pixel of your slice within the original image. Then you know exactly how to place it.

Comment: Regarding your specific situation: If you are very new to programming, you probably still don't know where to start with that last comment of mine. If that is the case, I think you might have set yourself too high of a goal in writing such an app by yourself. I suggest you stick to existing tutorials for now, which might not create an app exactly like the one you want, but can help you get a feeling for what it takes to write an app. Once you have a little experience in writing apps, you can ask much more specific questions where people on StackOverflow can help you out more easily.

Comment: @Jolly Just one last question: for rebuilding for pieces, can you name a few kotlin syntaxes which can be helpful to me (which includes data import and arranging).

Comment: You're going to need loops to iterate over pixel coordinates, other than that I don't know about specific kotlin language features which can help you here.